# Ajax dynamic function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I want to call query dynamically. everything seemed working except printing statement. It does not print the statement on the page.
I have two files  first detail.JSP and chat.JSP

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
    pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
   <%@ page import = "models.*"%>
 <%@ page import= "java.util.*"%>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title> chat system  </title>
 <script>

 function ajax(){
     var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
 req.readystatechange = function(){
        if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status==200){

            document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = req.responseText;



        }


    }

    req.open('GET','/member/chat.jsp',true);
    req.send();
}


setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000);
```

```
 <div id="container">

  <%

MemberDao dao = new MemberDao();

System.out.println("11111");

String tid=null;

tid = request.getParameter("tid");
System.out.println("tid:"+tid);
if(tid==null){
    System.out.println("tid is null");
     tid = (String)session.getAttribute("tid");

}else{
    System.out.println("tid is  not null");
    tid = request.getParameter("tid");
}







String myid =(String) session.getAttribute("idA");
MemberDto dto = dao.readOne(tid);
MemberDto idAdto = dao.readOne(myid);
WritingDao wdao = new WritingDao();
List<WritingDto> all = wdao.readMyMessage(myid);
System.out.println("==================="+all.size()+"conn::");
System.out.println("2222");
%>
```

```
 <h2>Member information</h2>
 <% System.out.println("333333");%>
 Send text <br/>
 ID:<%=dto.getId()%>  password:<%=dto.getPass()%><br/>
 <br/>
 <form action="/member/detailhandler.jsp"  class="login-form">
 <input type="text" name="tid" value =<%=tid%> ><br>
 <input type="text" id="text" name="text_name" style="height:200px;"            style="width: 200px;" 
  placeholder="your writing here" /><br/>
 <button>submit</button>
 </form>

 <% System.out.println("444444");%>
 <br/>
 The messages <br/><br/>

 <% 

 %> <div id="chat_box">


<div id ="chat"></div>
```

---

```
<a href="/pop/closepage.jsp">CLOSE</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The way I understood about AJAX is this ajax() function should call in

```
               <div id ="chat"></div>
```

but this function called after

```
               <% System.out.println("5555555");%>
```

So this is my first question: why ajax() function did not call in

```
               <div id ="chat"></div>
```

And this is my chat.JSP

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
 pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
 <%@ page import = "models.*"%>
 <%@ page import= "java.util.*"%>

  <% 
  String myid2 =(String) session.getAttribute("idA");
  System.out.println("ida:::::::::"+myid2);
  WritingDao wdao2 = new WritingDao();
  List<WritingDto> all2 = wdao2.readMyMessage(myid2);
  for(WritingDto t : all2) { %>
  <%System.out.println("getNum:::"+t.getNum()+":: id ::"+t.getContext()); %>

  FROM::
  <span style="color:green;"><%=t.getSendid() %>::  </span>
  <span style="color:brown;"><%=t.getContext() %>   </span> <br/>
  <% System.out.println("hello");%>

 <% }
 %>
```

I can see the Ajax() function is working to see the Sysout.out.print things
but the problem is

```
        FROM::
     <span style="color:green;"><%=t.getSendid() %>::  </span>
     <span style="color:brown;"><%=t.getContext() %>   </span> <br/>
     <% System.out.println("hello");%>

    <% }
    %>
```

This part does not shows on the screen.This is the second question i ask.

Comment: You will need to use browser dev tools network and inspect actual requests to see what status is and what is being returned(if anything). We can't troubleshoot both ends without knowing which end is causing the problem. Your browser dev tools will let you isolate this

Comment: thx charlietfl. I'm actually new to ajax. so is there any problem with my code?

Comment: No idea...not going to go through both ends line by line without some basic troubleshooting done. Are there any javascript errors in your browser dev tools console? Did you check in the network to see what status is of requests? You also learn to use debugging tools to isolate problems

Comment: i solved this with replace the ajax() function script at the bottom so strange..